# Do parry bonuses stack?

Tags: savage-worlds, stacking, savage-worlds-adventure-edition

Do parry bonuses stack?

So for example if a character is using two Rapiers (Parry +1, see p.72), do these stack, so their Parry is +2 ?

And continuing, does the +1 Parry bonus from the Trademark Weapon edge (see p.44) also stack with the parry from a weapon, i.e. would a Trademark rapier be a +2 Parry bonus?

And going even further ... what about a character having two Trademark Weapon edge, both rapier ... would their parry bonus be +4, i.e. +1 & +1 for one weapon, and +1 & +1 for the other weapon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Depends Upon Edition

In previous editions, they did not. [ShadowKras's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/144381/do-parry-bonuses-stack/144384#144384) cites this quite well.

In Adventure Edition, which your question is about, the answer is slightly different. Weapon Parry bonuses don't automatically stack but the Ambidextrous edge allows both to apply.

> **Ambidextrous** 
>   ...
>   If holding a weapon in each hand, Ambidextrous characters may stack Parry bonuses (if any) from both weapons.

Without Ambidextrous, only one Parry bonus applies.

Answer (score 3):

### Depends

When asked the same, one of the [Savage World forum admins](https://www.pegforum.com/forum/official-answers-on-rules-in-savage-worlds-core-companions/2662-duel-weapon-bonuses) said this:

> "*If a character is wielding a weapon in each hand that provides a bonus to parry from both weapons or only the highest?*"
>
> Inherent bonuses from different weapons do not stack (unless specifically stated as such) though penalties do.
>
> "*or a rapier in one hand and a enchanted dagger with +1 Parry in the other.*"
>
> The Fantasy Companion has a whole sidebar on magic bonuses and stacking, but in general, a flat bonus from magic does stack with an inherent one from the character via an Edge or an item.

So, using two rapiers would not grant you +1 to Parry twice, but different abilities, such as the Trademark Weapon edge, or the magical bonus to Parry would. Similarly, I would say that using *two* trademarked weapons would not stack, for the same reason given, they are coming from the same weapon and edge.